# C Linked List with Sentinel - Getting Access to nodes

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, sentinel

I'm struggeling to get this task (Implementing a *linked list*) done. I tried to build a so called sentinel, which sould make it easier. My question is, how do I get access to the actual elements? I tried to print the roots value (44) but I only get weired values. I assume, that these are adresses of memory (e.g. 6893440).

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node** init() {
    struct node **l;
    l = malloc(sizeof(struct node**));
    *l = NULL;
    return l;
}

void insert(struct node** l, int val) {
    struct node* p;
    if(*l == NULL) {
        p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        p->val = val;
        p->next = *l;
        *l = p;
    }
}

void main() {
    struct node* list;
    list = init();
    insert(list, 44); // create a (root)node with value 44
    printf("%d", list->val); // e.g. 6893440
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your compiler should be warning you about `insert(list, 44);` - you pass a `struct node*` instead of a `struct node**`

Comment: Consider all warnings as errors.

Comment: As mentioned above, `-Wall -Werror -Wextra` on gcc will [give you this](https://godbolt.org/z/kF8TcF).

Comment: Also, I think your `init()` should be returning `struct node*` not `**`, and in that function it should be `struct node* l` also not `**`, and `*l = NULL` should be `l->next = NULL`.  The `insert()` seems to do nothing at all if `*l != NULL`... which cannot be right.

Comment: Thank you guys! I was not aware of the fact, that there were errors tbh. I'm using the Atom IDE without any linters (not sure if this is the correct term, I mean Atom without any Plugins like Autocomplete), because my finals are supposed to be on paper and I really want to learn the syntax.
Edit: Forget to mention that the Compiler Explorer website is quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the list as a double pointer to node.

```
struct node** list;
```

Then you can access the value of the first node with

```
(*list)->val
```

**More info:**

In the implementation in data types such as lists in C we often use 2 typedefs to help with the readability of the code and eliminate lots of asterisks and ampersands. These are:

```
typedef struct node* ListNode;
typedef ListNode* List;
```

By doing this, you can declare a list simply by:

```
List list;
```

Note that the implementation of the list functions also becomes more readable by replacing `struct node*` and `struct node**` appropriately.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still working on that case, as you may have guessed, I am a CS student and the complete task is to implement this data structre and a cuple of functions like minimum, maximum, insert, delete ... I will update you as soon as I finish the delete function.

Comment: Cool! Note that if the answer solved this problem then mark this answer as correct. If you happen to have any problems while implementing the delete function then you can always make a new question.